# Chart.js is always increasing height on chart.resize()

Tags: charts, chart.js

I added chart.resize() inside of addData and removeData function, but it is always increasing height and it is never decreasing!

I am updating the chart when the user click on item of the menu. Some items have more than 100 datas e some others items have only 2 data and when have few data, the chart is always increasing height:

[horizontalBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYt6T.png)

Why is this happening?

```
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
var chartData = {
            labels: [<?php echo '"'.implode('","',  $chart_labels ).'"' ?>],
            datasets: [
                {
                    data: [<?php echo implode(',',  $chart_numbers ) ?>],
                    backgroundColor: '#184b8f',
                    hoverBackgroundColor: '#ef3e42'
                }
            ]
        };

        var barOptions = {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            tooltips: {
                enabled: false
            },
            hover: {
                animationDuration: 0
            },
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            scales : {
                xAxes : [{
                    gridLines : {
                        display: false
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        color: '#cfcfcf'
                    }
                } ],
                yAxes : [ {
                    gridLines : {
                        display: false
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        fontSize: 13,
                        fontFamily: "'Open Sans'",
                        fontWeight: 600,
                    }
                }]
            },
            animation: {
            duration: 500,
            easing: "easeOutQuart",
            }
        };

        function removeData(chart) {
            chart.data.labels.pop();
            chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
                dataset.data.pop();
            });
            chart.resize();
            chart.update();
        }

        function addData(chart, label, data) {
            chart.data.labels.push(label);
            chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
                dataset.data.push(data);
            });
            chart.resize();
            chart.update();
        }

        var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
        var myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
                        type: 'horizontalBar',
                        data: chartData,
                        options: barOptions
                    });
```

Answer (score 48):

I had the same thing. You have to put an empty div around the canvas.

Comment: with empty div, the canvas does not change the height, but I need increase or decrease height...

Comment: This is the correct answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer, saved a lot of time

Answer (score 5):

I've found some users had the same issue in this post: https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/issues/84

The solution for me was to change the chart's options to **maintainAspectRatio: false**.

```
    myChart.setOptions({
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

In laravel livewire i fixed adding `wire:ignore` to wrapper div

```
<div wire:ignore>
    <div class="chart-container" style="height: 80vh; width: 80vh;">
       <canvas id="bar-chart" height="800" width="1500"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked for me. I am using Laravel 9 with Livewire and Chartjs v3, i tried many solutions and this is the only one that worked. Excellent and thank you.

Answer (score -2):

I was having the same issue in a Bulma tile.

The fix was to set
`responsive: false` in the Chart.js script options area.